# Memory usage of JavaScript objects with numeric keys

Tags: javascript, memory

Looks like the memory required to hold a memory structure with Javascript Objects doesn't only rely on the number of stored objects but also the used keys.

Let's write, for example, this simple code in fiddlejs (link below):

```
for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
  o[i]={};
  for (var j=0; j<500; j++) {
    o[i][j]={};
    o[i][j]['abc'] = {};
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lespw7g/

Then run the script and open the Chrome memory tab (or take a memory snapshot with Firefox). At this point the profiler should show something like 16MB of allocated memory.

Now simply replace the `'abc'` key with `'900'` in the previous code. (link below)

```
for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
  o[i]={};
  for (var j=0; j<500; j++) {
    o[i][j]={};
    o[i][j]['900'] = {};
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cfm0n7xq/

Now the memory profiler shows that **more that 1400MB** is allocated which make a big difference.

Since this behavior is the same in both Chrome & Firefox, I would like to understand the underlying concepts to avoid unpleasant surprises in the futur when I'm using Javascript Objects

Thank you.

Comment: Although your question is why it happens, as for how to solve it and naturally avoid unpleasant surprises: use `Map` when you want a map. Since ES6, dynamic object keys are essentially an antipattern.

Comment: Just noticed this same thing. Did you ever figure out why? @jails