# JavaScript: how can I merge these two arrays of incomplete objects and make an array of complete objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have two arrays of objects

```js
const a = [
  { name: 'apple', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'berry', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'grape', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'broccoli', type: 'vegetable' },
  { name: 'cabbage', type: 'vegetable' },
]
const b = [
  { name: 'apple', amount: 4 },
  { name: 'berry', amount: 5 },
  { name: 'grape', amount: 3 },
  { name: 'broccoli', amount: 7 },
  { name: 'avocado', amount: 8 },
]
```

I need to write a function to output an array with objects with the same name being merged into one.

```js
const c = [
  { name: 'apple', type: 'fruit', amount: 4 },
  { name: 'berry', type: 'fruit', amount: 5 },
  { name: 'grape', type: 'fruit', amount: 3 },
  { name: 'broccoli', type: 'vegetable', amount: 7 },
  { name: 'cabbage', type: 'vegetable', amount: 0 },
  { name: 'avocado', type: undefined, amount: 8 },
]
```

As you can see here, objects that share the same name are merged into one object with a few exceptions:

1. if `type` field is missing, we would need to add it and make it `undefined`
2. if `amount` field is missing, we need to add it and make it `0`

Here is my attempt:

```js
function fillMissingFields(object) {
  console.log('object', object)
  let newObject = { ...object }
  if (object.type === undefined) {
    newObject = { ...object, type: undefined }
  }
  if (object.amount === undefined) {
    newObject = { ...newObject, amount: 0 }
  }
  return newObject
}

function join(a, b) {
  const results = []
  for (const aItem of a) {
    const bItems = b.filter((item) => item.name === aItem.name)
    let newObject
    if (bItems.length) {
      for (const bItem of bItems) {
        newObject = { ...newObject, ...bItem }
      }
      newObject = fillMissingFields({ ...newObject, ...aItem })
    } else {
      newObject = fillMissingFields(aItem)
    }
    results.push(newObject)
  }
  return results
}
```

Besides the fact that it has a really bad time complexity `O(n^2)`. It actually has a bug where if an object only appears in `b` array, that object will be omitted entirely from the new array.

Can anyone try to help me come up with a more robust and efficient algorithm to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a collection whose keys are the `name`s, whose values are the combined objects, which starts out with an undefined `type` and an amount of 0. Iterate through both arrays, assigning the property values as needed, then at the end, take the collection's values:

```js
const a = [
  { name: 'apple', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'berry', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'grape', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'broccoli', type: 'vegetable' },
  { name: 'cabbage', type: 'vegetable' },
];
const b = [
  { name: 'apple', amount: 4 },
  { name: 'berry', amount: 5 },
  { name: 'grape', amount: 3 },
  { name: 'broccoli', amount: 7 },
  { name: 'avocado', amount: 8 },
];

const objsByName = new Map();
const getObj = (name) => {
  if (!objsByName.has(name)) {
    objsByName.set(name, { name, type: undefined, amount: 0 });
  }
  return objsByName.get(name);
};
for (const { name, type } of a) {
  getObj(name).type = type;
}
for (const { name, amount } of b) {
  getObj(name).amount = amount;
}
console.log([...objsByName.values()]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I ask why you are using map instead of plain javascript object? Is this for performance?

Comment: You could use an object, but a Map is a tiny bit more semantically appropriate. Dynamic keys might be slightly worse performance-wise (not sure), can have rare name collisions with properties on `Object.prototype`, and can be harder to type in TypeScript than Maps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270531/memory-usage-of-javascript-objects-with-numeric-keys#comment115392196_65270531

Comment: Thank for the ply. Can you give me an example where it might have name collisions with properties on `Object.prototype`?

Comment: Eg if you had a name of `hasOwnProperty`, or `__proto__`, there could be unexpected behavior. Also see https://itnext.io/prototype-pollution-attack-on-nodejs-applications-94a8582373e7

Comment: that is interesting... I never knew that. btw I looked the stackoverflow post you attached above, the guy says "Since ES6, dynamic object keys are essentially an antipattern." Could you talk a little more about that? Or I wonder if there is any blog post that expound on that? Because I never knew it was an anti pattern...

Comment: It's unlikely to be a real issue in most cases, but could occasionally have pitfalls, so I'd like to just use a Map instead and not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

This following approach will work for dynamic objects which have different keys other than `name, type or amount`. Although there is one problem with that approach we can not define default values for each variable(like for amount default will be 0 or for other key default will be undefined). In my approach if any key is missing in any of the object the default value will be undefined.

```js
const a = [
  { name: 'apple', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'berry', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'grape', type: 'fruit' },
  { name: 'broccoli', type: 'vegetable' },
  { name: 'cabbage', type: 'vegetable' },
]
const b = [
  { name: 'apple', amount: 4 },
  { name: 'berry', amount: 5 },
  { name: 'grape', amount: 3 },
  { name: 'broccoli', amount: 7 },
  { name: 'avocado', amount: 8 },
]

const c = [...a, ...b];
const s = new Set();
let d = c.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(item => item.name === curr.name);
  if(index > -1) {
    acc[index] = {...acc[index], ...curr};
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  Object.keys(curr).forEach(key => s.add(key));
  return acc;
}, []);

let res = d.map(item => {
  let keyInObj = Object.keys(item);
  Array.from(s).forEach(actualKey => {
    if(!keyInObj.includes(actualKey)) {
      item[actualKey] = undefined;
    }
  });
  return item;
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code snippet creating a unique array of objects out of two arrays. If value is not present in amount or type, we are writing 0 or undefined respectively.

```js
const a = [
  { name: "apple", type: "fruit" },
  { name: "berry", type: "fruit" },
  { name: "grape", type: "fruit" },
  { name: "broccoli", type: "vegetable" },
  { name: "cabbage", type: "vegetable" },
];
const b = [
  { name: "apple", amount: 4 },
  { name: "berry", amount: 5 },
  { name: "grape", amount: 3 },
  { name: "broccoli", amount: 7 },
  { name: "avocado", amount: 8 },
];

let d = [...a, ...b];
const c = [];

d.map((o) => {
  const uniqIndex = c.findIndex((item) => item.name === o.name);
  uniqIndex === -1
    ? c.push({
        amount: 0,
        type: undefined,
        ...o,
      })
    : (c[uniqIndex] = {
        ...c[uniqIndex],
        ...o,
      });
});

console.log(c);
```